# Custom cursor doesn't work in IE9?

Tags: c#, css, winforms, cursor, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control in my form.
i used a custom cursor in my `CSS` code.every things fine in `IE8`

**Css Code**

```
cursor: url(AppDirectiry\Classes\QClasses\ClsDesignHtml\Cursors\arrow.ani);
```

but it seems dose not work in `IE9`.
any idea?

**Edited:**

I also used `.cur` cursor type but it seems also don't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202226/1098851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TMjvY/

This works in IE 9 now, just added ,auto onto the CSS.

Comment: every thing OK but i can not read cursor from my hard disk,in ie 8 is ok but in ie 9 already have problem:(

Comment: I noticed that AppDirectiry is misspelt in your CSS, please check that the URL is correct.

Comment: when i run my application i replace "AppDirectiry" in css file with address oh my bin folder,i use it for this target

Answer (score 3):

http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/2f3b25ea-bbc3-487b-8a0c-9850ae9f12ce/

http://jquery.kidsil.net/custom-cursor/

Those three links should help with fixing your issue, also pretty sure that most browsers don't support animated cursors, using a static one may solve your issue.

Comment: i tried this but don't work.i also used .cur cursor but it's also don't work.every things fine in IE8 but in IE9 don't work

Comment: Do you have a page with it on so I can see?

Comment: That code can't access the cursor as it's behind a cpanel login.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be in Quirks Mode