# Custom cursor:url(/img/cursor.gif) marked as invalid property

Tags: css, cross-browser, cursor, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to create a little banner for my site and I found myself lost trying to customize the cursor when hovering it. If I use a built-in value like

```
cursor:waiting
```

it works, but if I change it to

```
cursor: url(/img/cursor.gif)
```

it doesn't work anymore... 
I tried also with a PNG image and the result has been the same: just the default cursor..
I copied also the property from w3school and still doesn't work with my CSS.. (In w3school it worked also with custom images). In Chrome if I inspect the element the css inspector shows a yellow triangle /!\ saying 'invalid property' referred to cursor: url(/img/cursor.gif).

The path should be correct, I also copied the cursor.gif in the same folder of the CSS and still doesn't work.. Where is the problem?
Thank you in advance to everybody!

Comment: Tryed also to change the path to url(img/cursor.gif). Now the browser loads the gif in the inspector but still doesn't work..

Comment: I'm now asking myself if is the animated gif file format supported by the browsers..

Comment: @Ken After many hacks I discovered that the size was too high to be displayed. Now it works, but it is not animated.. Searching if another file format could solve, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189250/animated-cursor-support-in-web-applications). It seems that the way in which I am is going nowhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hacks I discovered that the size was too high to be displayed. Now it works, but it is not animated.. Searching if another file format could solve, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189250/animated-cursor-support-in-web-applications). It seems that the way in which I am is going nowhere..

The working (but not animating) code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fcole90/QrReu/1/).

HTML

```
<div id="amiciCuccioliAd">

    <img class="adTitle" src="http://www.sardegnaannunci.com/amiciCuccioliAd/img/adTitle.png">
    <img class="pets" src="http://www.sardegnaannunci.com/amiciCuccioliAd/img/pets.png">



</div>
```

CSS

```
#amiciCuccioliAd{
height:140px;
width:250px;
background-color:red;
border:0px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px; 
cursor:url(http://www.sardegnaannunci.com/amiciCuccioliAd/cursor.gif), wait; 
}

/*Questo è per cambiare il cursore sul #amiciCuccioliAd*/
#amiciCuccioliAd:hover { 
cursor:url(http://www.sardegnaannunci.com/amiciCuccioliAd/cursor.gif), wait; 
}

/*Questo casino è per mettere un'immagine al centro!*/
#amiciCuccioliAd > .adTitle{
display:block;
width:237px;
height:35px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:5px;
}

#amiciCuccioliAd > .pets{
display:block;
float:left;
padding-left:4px;
}
```

Comment: Found also this [http://ye5.blogspot.it/2011/01/animated-mouse-cursor-on-mozilla.html](http://ye5.blogspot.it/2011/01/animated-mouse-cursor-on-mozilla.html)

Comment: Were you able to use large size image as a cursor? It seems like the maximum size is 32 * 32

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with with the best work around I had was to just upload it to an image host and use that url instead of a local one.

Comment: Also hosting the image doesn't work for me. It seems that the problem lies in the animation of the gif..