# Can't use .ani cursor in css?

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I have custom my website's cursor. But css cursor:  url(...); Only work with .gif .png or .cur.  I want use .ani file but it's only work in IE.

```
cursor: url(../img/mcursor.cur),auto;
```

Comment: .ani is a windows-specific format. no surprise it only works in IE, since MS is of the firm opinion that other operating systems are figments of misguided users' opinions.

Answer (score 5):

IE supports .ani and .cur using Windows APIs. Webkit/Blink and Firefox have their own parsers for .cur (see [ICOImageDecoder](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/image-decoders/ico/ICOImageDecoder.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) and [nsICODecoder](http://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/image/decoders/nsICODecoder.cpp)), but they do not have parsers for the ani format (as evidenced by no results from a code search for [ANIHEADER] etc.)

See [Animated cursor support in web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189250/animated-cursor-support-in-web-applications) for animated cursor support on browsers other than IE. Basically, at this time nobody else really supports any animated cursors.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a library which will allow you to use `.ani` cursors in the browser. It uses a JavaScript parser to convert `.ani` cursors into CSS animations at runtime.

- [Blog post](https://jordaneldredge.com/blog/rendering-animated-ani-cursors-in-the-browser/)
- NPM module [`ani-cursor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ani-cursor)

Comment: Hey, this is genial! Thank you for building it! I'm using it already and I'm trying to use .ani files installed locally in my project. Is it possible? I am getting errors when trying this.