# Custom pointer cursor on image map area reverts to default

Tags: html, css, image

I am attempting to change the cursor in a specific element.

Changing

```css
area {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

to

```css
area {
    cursor: url("http://fivebs.net/fiddle/cursor.ani"), pointer;
}
```

doesn't work. However, using the default cursors (wait, help, etc.) works:

```css
area {
    cursor: url("http://fivebs.net/fiddle/cursor.gif"), help;
}
```

Tried modifying global cursor parameters, different containers, java script, different CSS styles, etc. Also looked up most previous stackoverflow questions, and used jsfiddle to test them out (with previous google searches).

HTML

```html
<div>
    <map id="world" name="world">
        <area shape="circle" alt="Africa" title="Africa" coords="682,462,97" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="afr.style.visibility='visible'; afr.src='africa.png';" onmouseout="afr.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Americas" title="Americas" coords="228,198,123" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="ame.style.visibility='visible'; ame.src='americas.png';" onmouseout="ame.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Asia/Pacific" title="Asia/Pacific" coords="1110,412,122" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="asi.style.visibility='visible'; asi.src='asiapacific.png';" onmouseout="asi.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Europe" title="Europe" coords="627,136,98" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="eur.style.visibility='visible'; eur.src='europe.png';" onmouseout="eur.style.visibility='hidden';" />
    </map>
    <img alt="Africa" style="position:absolute;top:559px;left:779px;visibility:hidden;" id="afr" src="africa.png" />
    <img alt="Americas" style="position:absolute;top:321px;left:351px;visibility:hidden;" id="ame" src="americas.png" />
    <img alt="Asia/Pacific" style="position:absolute;top:534px;left:1232px;visibility:hidden;" id="asi" src="asiapacific.png" />
    <img alt="Europe" style="position:absolute;top:234px;left:725px;visibility:hidden;" id="eur" src="europe.png" />
    <img id="worldmap" alt="world map" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap.png" usemap="#world" />
</div>
<img alt="Ta Da" src="http://fivebs.net//fiddle/tada.png" />
```

CSS

```css
#worldmap {
    position: relative;
    cursor: url("http://fivebs.net/fiddle/cursor.ani"), url("http://fivebs.net/fiddle/cursor.gif"), auto;
}
area {
    cursor: url("http://fivebs.net/fiddle/cursor.gif"), help;
}
```

Would be preferable to be able to use a custom cursor, on hover-over-area, on said image map.

Been testing this Jsfiddle: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/FiveBs/5w5jfxgz/)

**Update**

Apparently the  tag is outside of DOM, and such cannot be altered. Any suggestions (apart from using SVG)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is the extension of the file that you are trying to use as custom cursor..

[Can't use .ani cursor in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330170/cant-use-ani-cursor-in-css)

Comment: According to my tests, using both PNG and GIF yields the same results @Carlos27 Example > cursor: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/Z70sotJNZ8nyU/giphy.gif"), pointer; It only allows me to change it outside the designated area/hotspot.

Comment: correct, but your initial post shows that you are trying to use a .ani file for a cursor which is not supported.

Comment: You can also give an id to the <area> tag and then in css use the #id selector to assign your custom cursor. That should fix your problem.