# Why doesn't my "gif" file animate on my HTML document

Tags: html, css

So I am just trying to learn how to change the cursor in html and css. Instead of having the default cursor, I changed it to an image of a lion (32px x 32px) when you hover over a text. What I am having trouble with is making the animation on my .gif to work. I have my code written to when the cursor hovers over a text, the cursor changes to the lion image and when the text is clicked on then the cursor should play the animated gif.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Testing Cursors</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hotpink">Hello, my name is <a class="cursor_hover" href="#">Jennifer</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body{
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
background-color: red;
}

.hotpink{
    background: hotpink;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    
}

.cursor_hover{
    cursor: url(images/lion.png), auto;
}


.cursor_hover:active{
    cursor: url(images/animation.gif), auto;    
}
```

inside my "images" folder:

lion.png and animation.gif

I am not sure if this matters for the gif but it is 2.25KB, width is 54px, and height is 36px.

I was using Microsoft Edge browser to run my VS code using Live Server but it wasn't working so I switched to Google Chrome and still doesn't animate.

Comment: Please see [Animated cursor support in web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189250/animated-cursor-support-in-web-applications) and [Using URL values for the cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated cursor support in web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189250/animated-cursor-support-in-web-applications)

Comment: Yeah it does. Much appreciate it